# Menu icon is not displayed when using navigation drawer activity

Tags: android

Please view the below xml file. I have used icons for each menu. In my code, the icons appear in the left side(no issues in code). But when I run the code, my output doesn't show the icon. It displays a grey square box in the icon region. Please help:

activity_main_drawer.xml:

```
<menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_1"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/settings_label" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_2"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_wp"
        android:title="@string/remote_label" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_3"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_twitter"
        android:title="@string/interactive_label" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_4"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_gplus"
        android:title="@string/credits_label" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your layout with below given code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_dash_board" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool">

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:openDrawer="start">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_dash_board"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
                app:menu="@menu/activity_dash_board_drawer" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your navigation view, do this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and then initialize components in your onCreate method,

```
drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)

    toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

***activity_main_drawer.xml*** should be under `menu` folder  and to set this menu with its icons you should use [Navigationvue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) .

Related to the documentation : you have to set :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

 <!-- Your contents -->

 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```